# API - cURL with GET and POST in same request

Tags: json, post, curl, get

Sorry if this has been answered but I've been googling for a while and can't seem to find anything. I'm wondering how to send a GET & POST in the same cURL payload if that's possible? In other words, send a GET request from one website's API (in my case returns json data) and then have this post to another application all in the same request. Basically I'm trying to do the same sort of thing that IFTTT does, for ex. when API-a posts news story, then post  news story to API-b.

Basically, I can currently send a payload of the text for the url that I'm trying to get to a webhook, but what I'd like to do is have the payload GET the info from a URL then POST this to another url. Is this possible in the same payload?

Comment: I don't think you mean that this needs to be done with a single request, but rather within a single server-side script execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible with HTTP.

You need to first get the results of the first transfer and then send that to the next one, but you can indeed do that in a single command line if you'd like. Something like this:

```
curl http://1.example.com/get.html | curl -d@- http://2.example.com/post.php
```

Comment: I will try that, thanks. What does -d@- mean? I know -d is data but I've never seen the @ symbol in there

Comment: "-d @filename" is for reading the data from a file, while "-d @-" reads the data from stdin.